# How do I line up subsequent slides with Powerpoint's Motion Paths?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm using Powerpoint's Motion Paths to move images around in my slides.  The problem is, on subsequent slides I need the previously-moved images to appear in their Motion Path destinations and I can't seem to get them to line up perfectly.  The resulting effect is a smoothly moving image that suddenly "jumps" a few pixels on a slide transition.

How can I get images to appear *exactly* at the end of their Motion Paths in subsequent slides?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution is described in details in the article [PowerPoint 2010: Perfecting the Motion Path](http://iconlogic.blogs.com/weblog/2011/09/powerpoint-2010-perfecting-the-motion-path.html).

The basic idea is that it is much easier to look at the problem upside-down.

If the slides are S1 and S2, start with S2 and then create the matching motion path in S1 that
ends in the starting-point of S2.
See the article for more details, including screenshots.

A comment following the above article recommends using the free [Motion Path End Position](http://skp.mvps.org/mpepos.htm)
add-in to PowerPoint which creates duplicate shapes at the position where each of the selected motion path animation ends. Using this tool you can quickly determine the end position of the animation at design time.